# Would this be a legal move in a Matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Here I have a matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
    b^2c^2 & bc & b+c \\
    c^2a^2 & ca & c+a \\
    a^2b^2 & ab & a+b \\
    \end{pmatrix}

I was wondering can I do the following operation on this:

$C2 \to C2 \times C2$

So it would give me the following:

\begin{pmatrix}
    b^2c^2 & b^2c^2 & b+c \\
    c^2a^2 & c^2a^2 & c+a \\
    a^2b^2 & a^2b^2 & a+b \\
    \end{pmatrix}

This is needed in order to prove the determinant is equal to zero.

Comment: You can do this, if you want, but it will not let you conclude anything about how the determinants of the two matrices are related.

Comment: @MorganRodgers I believe the OP wants to prove that the determinant of the first matrix vanishes by using multilinearity (and perhaps alternating property) of $\det$ (with respect to columns). As such I believe the operation of multiplying a column with itself is not valid.

Comment: Morgan is right, sure you could do this, its a column operation (scaling a column by itself), but the determinant of the matrix will change. Remember that if you want to maintain enough information in a matrix $M$ so that it still has the same Jordan Normal Form $J$ (determinant is product of the diagonal), then you need the form $J = X^{-1}MX$. By doing row/column eliminations, you are performing $XMY = P$ where $P$ is a row/column reduced matrix, and no longer retains the eigenvalues or determinant of $M$

Comment: So that means if I scaled the column by itself will it change the determinant of the Matrix. @peek-a-boo says is correct I want to prove the matrix is actually equal to zero by using the property that due to the same column it will be equal to zero.

Comment: @TyJensen right... that's what I meant to say; that the operation of multiplying a column with itself will change the determinant in a non-trivial way (rather than the trivial constant factors which come up from doing only the "elementary operations") perhaps I misunderstood/overlooked the point being made by Morgan

Comment: Actually what I did is that I multiplied the rows separately and then divided by 'abc'! That actually worked out indeed! Thanks for the help by the way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to think in terms of homogeneous symmetric polynomials' degrees. Subtract $ab+bc+ca$ times the second column from the first, thus changing $b^2c^2$ to $-abc(b+c)$. Now add $abc$ times the third column to the first; it should vanish then. Explicitly$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
b^{2}c^{2}\\
c^{2}a^{2}\\
a^{2}b^{2}
\end{array}\right)-\left(ab+bc+ca\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
bc\\
ca\\
ab
\end{array}\right)+abc\left(\begin{array}{c}
b+c\\
c+a\\
a+b
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{array}\right).$$

Answer (score -1):

Since this will (for most $a$ and $b$) change the value of the determinant, lets use co-factor multiplication by your matrix $M$ to prove this, which shouldn't be *too* bad given it is a $3x3$ matrix. I will denote each $2x2$ co factor as $A_i$ for simplicity.
$$det(M) = (b+c)det(A_1) - (c+a)det(A_2) + (a+b)det(A_3)$$
$$det(M) = (b+c)(a^3c^2b-a^3b^2c)-(c+a)(c^3b^2a-c^3a^2b)+(a+b)(b^3c^2a -b^3a^2c)$$
Hmm... maybe this wasn't the right approach but whatever too late now
$$det(M) = (a^3c^2b^2-a^3b^3c+a^3c^3b-a^3b^2c^2)-(b^3c^3a-b^3a^2c^2+b^3c^2a^2-b^3a^3c)+(c^3b^2a^2-c^3a^3b+c^3b^3a-c^3a^2b^2)$$
Jesus christ... notice that we can take out a $a^3, b^3$ or $c^3$
$$det(M) = a^3(c^2b^2-b^3c+c^3b-b^2c^2)-b^3(c^3a-a^2c^2+c^2a^2-a^3c)+c^3(b^2a^2-a^3b+b^3a-a^2b^2)$$
And then do even better by noticing we can take out a $ab, bc$ or $ac$
$$det(M) = a^3bc(cb-b^2+c^2-bc)-b^3ca(c^2-ac+ca-a^2)+c^3ba(ba-a^2+b^2-ab)$$
Now some terms cancel... thank god....
$$det(M) = a^3bc(-b^2+c^2)-b^3ca(c^2-a^2)+c^3ba(-a^2+b^2)$$
Rearrange some more..
$$det(M) = -a^3bc(b^2-c^2)-b^3ca(c^2-a^2)-c^3ba(a^2-b^2)$$
Factor out a $-abc$
$$det(M) = -abc(a^2(b^2-c^2)+b^2(c^2-a^2)+c^2(a^2-b^2))$$
Distribute
$$det(M) = -abc((a^2b^2-a^2c^2)+(b^2c^2-b^2a^2)+(c^2a^2-c^2b^2))$$
Reorder terms
$$det(M) = -abc(a^2b^2-b^2a^2-a^2c^2+c^2a^2+b^2c^2-c^2b^2)$$
Thus
$$det(M) = -abc(0)$$
$$det(M) = 0$$
I retract my former statement that this wouldn't be too bad, but luckily I denoted the co factors as $A_i$, saving me loads of time.